Woocommerce quantity add package text
I want to add package text next to the number in the Woocommerce quantity field, but I was not successful.
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'add_text_to_quantity_for_specific_category' );

function add_text_to_quantity_for_specific_category() {
    // Specify the category ID here
    $category_id = 87;

    global $product;

    // Get category IDs of the current product
    $product_categories = $product->get_category_ids();

    // If the product belongs to certain category, add the text
    if ( in_array( $category_id, $product_categories ) ) {
        echo '<div class="qty-wrapper">';
        echo '<div class="qty">Sq Ft</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

Please can you help me, how can I do this?
I want to do something similar to this area on WooCommerce.
<div class="product-box-calcute-left col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="product-quantity-Box">
        <input type="hidden" id="hidquantity" value="9000">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="37120">
        <button onclick="return false;" class="decrease btn-number" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="product_quantity">-</button>
        <input type="number" onkeyup="isNumeric(this)" min="5" max="9000" class="product-basket-quantity input-number" name="product_quantity" id="quantity" value="5">
         <span class="product_unit">Adet</span>
        <button onclick="return false;" class="increase btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="product_quantity">+</button>
    </div>
</div>




